# S2S Vpn Windows 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, site-to-site-vpn

I am trying to set up a S2S VPN with 2 Windows 2019 servers.
Lets say we have a Site A and a Site B.

So I've setup two Windows 2019 server with Routing and Remote Access enabled.
On both sites I added a Demand-dial interface.
Site B is running well. It connects via the Demand-dial interface to Site A.
Site A is not able to connect. The error message is "The interface is already connected".

When I disconnect the Demand-dial interface on Site B. Site A is able to connect. After that Site B is able to connect too.

So it is only running, when Site A is connecting before Site B. The other way round is not working.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect from both sides? Only one connection is necessary.

Comment: All documentations require two connections. Like you can see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJH56qMNRu8. With only one it is not working.

Comment: Well, then my S2S has been working on magic for the last years.